# Generate new proto

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, grpc

I have a `<Podspec file name>.podspec` equivalent to the [standard GRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/objective-c) one.

I don't know how to run the script in here that generates new `.pbobjc.h/.pbobjc.m files for each .proto file.`

Does anyone know what command I should run in the command line to trigger generating these new files per the script in the `.podspec` file?

Here is some more context for the script in the `.podspec`:

```
      # Run protoc with the Objective-C and gRPC plugins to generate protocol messages and gRPC clients.
  # You can run this command manually if you later change your protos and need to regenerate.
  # Alternatively, you can advance the version of this podspec and run `pod update`.
  s.prepare_command = <<-CMD
    mkdir -p #{dir}
    #{protoc} \
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=#{plugin} \
        --objc_out="Pods/LndRpc" \
        --grpc_out="Pods/LndRpc" \
        -I $GOPATH/src \
        -I $GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis \
        -I "Pods/!ProtoCompiler" \
        -I "." \
        ./*.proto
  CMD

  # The --objc_out plugin generates a pair of .pbobjc.h/.pbobjc.m files for each .proto file.
  s.subspec 'Messages' do |ms|
    ms.source_files = "#{dir}/*.pbobjc.{h,m}"
    ms.header_mappings_dir = dir
    ms.requires_arc = false
    # The generated files depend on the protobuf runtime.
    ms.dependency 'Protobuf'
  end

  # The --objcgrpc_out plugin generates a pair of .pbrpc.h/.pbrpc.m files for each .proto file with
  # a service defined.
  s.subspec 'Services' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = "#{dir}/*.pbrpc.{h,m}"
    ss.header_mappings_dir = dir
    ss.requires_arc = true
    # The generated files depend on the gRPC runtime, and on the files generated by `--objc_out`.
    ss.dependency 'gRPC-ProtoRPC'
    ss.dependency "#{s.name}/Messages"
  end
```